# Cross compile ARM Portable Executable on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, arm, cross-compiling, portable-executable

I was able to cross compile for x86 and x86-64 PE files on Linux using:

```
sudo apt install -y mingw-w64
```

I would like to know if there is a possibility to cross compile PE files for other architectures on Ubuntu such as ARM.

Comment: yes, either run linux on the target and compile natively or get a cross compiler, if for example you want to develop on an x86.

Comment: @old_timer Unfortunately, I haven't found any gcc or clang based cross compiler for ARM PE.

Comment: so the pe file format specifically, I see a doc on it so if there arent already tools you can write an elf to pe converter.